# Convert C# Console>Service? How to retain dictionary when Class calls itself?

Tags: c#, .net, service

I'm attempting to transform a simple console application so that it may be used as a service using a nested `Service` class (relevant code below). The intent is to create a service to perform the actions within the `Run` method more-or-less at a set interval (eventually, ~hourly).

In short, the Service's `OnStart` calls my own `Start` method once, which creates a timer. Inside the timer, I'm creating an instance of the `Program` class, and performing the `Run` method till it finishes. I believe this is a valid implementation of what I want that doesn't leave resources outstanding.

Part of what the `Run` method does is build a dictionary of actions it was unable to perform on the file system, and I would like to retain the dictionary in subsequent calls to `Run` in order to attempt these actions again, if possible. What would be the best implementation to accomplish this? I'm a bit green and not terribly confident I'm doing things correctly, but I'm attempting to get up to speed as quickly as possible, so any assistance is appreciated.

```
partial class Program{
    static object timerLck = new object();

    public class Service : ServiceBase{
        public Service(){
            ServiceName = Program.ServiceName;
        }
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args){
            Program.Start(args);
        }
        protected override void OnStop(){
            Program.Stop();
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args){
        if (!Environment.UserInteractive)
            using (var service = new Service())
                ServiceBase.Run(service);
        else{
            Start(args);
            Stop();
        }
    }

    private static void Start(string[] args){
        Timer t = new Timer(CallTimer, null, 0, 50000);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void Stop(){
        //???
    }

    static void CallTimer(object state){
        bool Lock = false;
        try{
            Lock = Monitor.TryEnter(timerLck);
            if (Lock){
                Program Prg = new Program()
                var task = Task.Run((Func<Task<int>>)Prg.Run);
                task.Wait();
            }
        }
        finally{
            if (Lock) Monitor.Exit(timerLck);
        }
    }

    //Perform the repeated actions here 
    private async Task<int> Run()
    {
        Dictionary<string, Metadata> d = new Dictionary<string, Metadata>();
        //...            
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you need to run some code on a scheduled basis (e. g. hourly), use the Windows Task Scheduler.  That is what it is designed for.  By doing that, you could likely keep your app as a console application with few changes.  As for keeping track of actions that need to be retried, you'll probably have to store that in a file of some sort.

Comment: Indeed Microsoft itself went and moved a number of regular operations out of services and into the Task Sheduler. Functions like chkdsk, defrag, Windows Update and more.

Comment: @Christopher She's doing a windows service which has more functionality than a scheduled task. For example, they can be configured to restart on failure and run on startup, etc.

Comment: @YuliBonner: The task sheduler has all those options. And then a ton. It also needs no complete rewriting of a Console Application. You might be thinking of an older model of the Task Sheduler. The current one is really powerfull.

Comment: @Christopher fair enough, a schedule task would probably work too. My solution should work if she decided to go that route too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just have Run accept a Dictionary as a parameter and return the populated Dictionary.

```
private async Task<Dictionary<string, Metadata>> Run(Dictionary<string, 
    Metadata> previousErrors)
{
    Dictionary<string, Metadata> d = new Dictionary<string, Metadata>();
    //...            
    return d;
}
```

Then set a  property PreviousErrors on your Program class to the returned Dictionary.

```
static void CallTimer(object state){
        bool Lock = false;
        try{
            Lock = Monitor.TryEnter(timerLck);
            if (Lock){
                Program Prg = new Program()
                var task = Task.Run(()=>Run(PreviousErrors));
                PreviousErrors = task.Result;
            }
        }
    finally{
        if (Lock) Monitor.Exit(timerLck);
    }
}
```

Note, that I'm only addressing your question not the quality of the rest of the code. It could do with improvements that are outside of the scope of your question.

Comment: Yuri, I appreciate your feedback! Now that you put it in text, it seems obvious to simply return the dictionary in `Run`. I modified `var task = Task.Run(() => Prg.Run(PreviousErrors));` to avoid a reference to non-static method `Run` error, and it looks good so far. Regarding your quality note, if you get a chance, would you be able to briefly comment on what you would suggest I revisit? I appreciate the opportunity to improve my understanding!

Comment: @Alice Use https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for general code reviews. Also, if this answer works for you, please select it as the answer, so I get some reputation. Thanks!

Comment: Yuri, I appreciate your help and have done as you suggested; I didn't realize the code review site existed. I have posted my question at the link below if you felt available to comment on the piece that you indicated I should revisit, but please don't feel any pressure to do so if you are very busy: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/187126/convert-simple-c-consoleservice-to-perform-repeated-api-calls-and-file-system Again, thanks for the help!